# What's the reverse of underlying?

Tags: word-request, antonyms

When one thing is based on another, we can refer to one of them using the word "underlying". For example, if object A is based on object B, we can say:

> the underlying B

What are good ways to refer to the other object, A?

Comment: **underlying** refers to that upon which something is based. What is the opposite of "that upon which something is based"?  That upon which it is not based?  That which is based upon it? It has no opposite.  If you want to ask, "How to we say that something is based on something else?" the answer is in the question.

Comment: I agree that "antonym" is the wrong word, but I think it's clear what's being asked here, so I edited it. Feel free roll back my edit if I've misinterpreted the question.

Comment: If it was in OOP (object-oriented programming), base classes and derived classes would be the common terms. Some flavors of OOP are prototype-based, and though the term "prototype" is more common, I'd say it's apt to use "base object" and "derived object".

Answer (score 2):

The **outcome** A Or

The **resultant** A.

The **derivative** A

Also, A is **dependent** on B.

Answer (score 1):

Other ways to show a **progressive dependent path** from object B to object A are

> A is a **derivative of** B
>   A is **evolved from** B
>   A is **more advanced** than B
>   A is **based on** B
>   A is **refined from** B
>   A is **created from** B

All these sentences mean that **B underlies A**

Answer (score 1):

- A is derived from B.
- A is subclassed from B.
- A is a wrapper for B.

.

- The derivative A.  (has a specific meaning in a mathematical context.)
- The subclass A.
- The wrapper A.
- The superficial A.
- The surface A.  (has a specific meaning in a mathematical context.)

Per Damkerng's suggestion:

- The derived class A.
- The derived object A.